# Can't find the longest string in a list

Tags: python, string

I am trying to build a program that finds the ideal word given the available letters for scrabble. I have downloaded a file with all the possible words in scrabble and I am trying to find the longest one.

```
import csv

with open('dictionary.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)

longest = ""
for i in data:
    if len(i) > len(longest):
        longest = i
print(longest)
```

The output:

```
/Users/jason/PycharmProjects/Scrabble/venv/bin/python /Users/jason/PycharmProjects/Scrabble/PossibleWordsFinder.py
['aa']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

For some reason, the program doesn't find the correct string. I have tried different variations of the aforementioned code but none seem to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I notice that `print(longest)` isn't printing the *string* `"aa"` but rather the *list* `["aa"]`. Looks like `data` is a list of lists, where each inner list has length 1 and contains a string. That means that `len(i)` will always be 1, regardless of what's inside list `i`.

Comment: It is likely that you need `if len(i[0]) > len(longest):` not `if len(i) > len(longest):` and `longest = i[0]` instead of `longest = i`. (which is what @jjramsey was pointing out)

Comment: Use `data = [word for row in reader for word in row]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are not working with strings, you are working with lists.
Your `print()` gives a list with a string. So what you think is every word as a string is actually every word as a string but inside a list, and every list has one item (i.e the word), so `len()` is returning 1 for every item.

This is what I came up with to fix your problem (haven't tested it yet):

```
import csv

with open('dictionary.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)

longest = ""
for i in data:
    if len(i[0]) > len(longest):
        longest = i[0]
print(longest)
```

Hope this helps! Comment if it doesn't work, I'll try to help you.